# I need some tool to view HTTP requests

Tags: http, proxy, firefox-addon, http-headers

It's probably some browser extension or a proxy.

For example, I open google.com, and type something and press 'Search'. And I want to see all params of http-request (like, method, domain, params etc).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

It will show all the HTTP requests leaving your computer. Covering all the browsers, and all the other applications.

Comment: This isn't a mozilla-plugin, however.

Comment: what about localhost:xxxx to localhost:yyyy request?

Answer (score 2):

**[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)**

> [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) is a free and open-source packet analyzer. It is used for
>   network troubleshooting, analysis, software and communications
>   protocol development, and education. Originally named Ethereal, the
>   project was renamed Wireshark in May 2006 due to trademark issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Firefox, HttpFox is excellent for this. Can inspect all GET/POST content, headers etc.

Answer (score 1):

If using Firefox, Live HTTP Headers is a nice add-on:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using Windows, disregard this answer.

I used to use Wireshark, but I recently started using [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en) which is very nice as well. If you have your own custom protocol (which I know the OP does not), it is **very easy** to write your own protocol parser, which is a big PITA with Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one and really cool one:

[web-sniffer.net/](http://web-sniffer.net/)

Answer (score 0):

httpwatch An HTTP Viewer and HTTP Sniffer for IE and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)'s Net section has some of the relevant information, but it's more of response/time loading time. The headers are present however.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) plugins for Firefox to see live data coming from a website.

If you're just looking for what could be in it, take a look at the w3c standard [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html), the [original RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822), or the [updated RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843)

If you are going to do monitoring and debugging in Firefox only.

Simple, lightweight, clean, and easy to use

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes proxy is not a good solution, since it makes impact on your connection settings.

Check the [HTTP Debugger Pro](http://www.httpdebugger.com).

I supports both HTTP and HTTPS connections for all browsers, including Chrome.